# meaning of letter "f" after year in financial report

Tags: annual-report

It's a report chart showing the evolution of construction sector through the years . The titles of the columns read:

"2017", "2018f" and "2019f".

Does this mean the numbers below the titles are not final and could vary?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Probably f for foretasted, but its hard to say without seeing the source.

Comment: My guess is that the f means forecasted for that year (Foretasted quid?)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026570/suffix-of-f-on-float-value

Comment: I think quid and Bob Baerker got it right! Thank you very much!

Comment: @BobBaerker autocorrect bites me again!

Comment: As long as it's an oral thermometer, you're gonna be just fine!